# Need to limit the date in a slicer by today's date in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, filtering, dax, measure

I am building a report in Power BI Desktop, created a slicer - **YearMonthSort** - which has data selection by Year-Month

Plz, see the screenshot below:

[image]

My goal is to limit data in this slicer as -
**2015-07** to **today's date** 
                   (whichever it will be when users will look at the data,
                    in the same format - "**YYYY-MM**")

In the "Filters" section I can select my starting year as 2015-07,
but having problem setting today's date.

I tried to create the new Measure, but not sure where to place it,
or, may be there is another way to perform this:

```
      IsToday = FORMAT(TODAY(), "mm/yyyy")
```

I only just started to learn this, 
Thank you for help in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the following:

I am assuming that you are using a calendar table that is joined to your fact table on a date field and that your year sort column is calculated with reference to the 'date' field in your calendar table.

Assuming, this is true you can create a calculated column that will flag whether or not the date field is before or after today. This can be achieved by using the following DAX:

```
IsToday =
SWITCH (
    TRUE (),
    'Calendar'[Date]
        <= NOW (), 1,
    0
)
```

Then, in your visual add a 'Visual Level Filter' using this new column and set it to 1.

Comment: @SteiloK yes, I am using a calendar table Dimension.Date, which is joined to my fact table - it's joined by the field Dimension.Date.Date -> FactTableName.ServiceDate      The field YearMonthSort is just a label                       In your 'IsToday' calculation - what is 'Calendar'[Date]?

Comment: @SteiloK   OMG, It worked !!!! Thank you   I kept adding a measure instead of calculated column - that was my mistake  :)